# What's the relation between the q term and the number of correct digits in the Chudnovsky algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, pi

This is the Chudnovsky algorithm for computing the digits of pi:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm

It has a term q which sets the upper bound on the number of iterations run on the algorithm. However, on this page, there's no relation between q and the number of correct digits that that q will produce. What is the relation between the two?

Comment: Have you looked at the references listed on that wiki page? in particular the 8th one.

Comment: That 8th one is quite long. What specifically in it are you referring to?

Comment: The [second sentence of the introduction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.00533.pdf) says: "It is particularly efficient, because it yields on average 14.1816 decimal digits of π per iteration (see Thm. 10.13)."